# What is the purpose of all 18-20 js files that gets loaded with any MVC application by default

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

What is the purpose of all 18-20 js files that gets loaded with any MVC application by default?
Can we get the information about all files and their purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read some information at:
http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_folders.asp
and
http://www.gxclarke.org/2012/01/initial-files-mvc3-website-script.html